# TLS eror installing webapp from storage account arm template

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to deploy a new Azure Resource group using a ARM template. The template uses a webdeploy package that is hosted on my storage account. Now when I try to deploy the template I get an error.

This is the powershell command I run

> New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name $Name -ResourceGroupName $Name -TemplateUri $ArmTemplateUrl -TemplateParameterFile $paramJsonFile

Now in my parameters file I have a reference to a web deploy package that included a sas token in the URL:

```
"singleMsDeployPackageUrl":  {
                                 "value":  "https://<MYNAME>.blob.core.windows.net/sitecore/Sitecore%208.2%20rev.%20170407_single.scwdp.zip?<MYTOKEN>"
                             },
```

I posted the full error below. This used to work but something changed in Azure?

> New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 1:43:59 PM - Resource Microsoft.Resources/deployments 'habitatazure-application' failed with message '{
>     "status": "Failed",
>     "error": {
>       "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
>       "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
>       "details": [
>         {
>           "code": "DeploymentFailed",
>           "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage 
>   details.",
>           "details": [
>             {
>               "code": "Conflict",
>               "message": "{\r\n  \"status\": \"failed\",\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"ResourceDeploymentFailure\",\r\n    \"message\": \"The resource operation 
>   completed with terminal provisioning state 'failed'.\",\r\n    \"details\": [\r\n      {\r\n        \"code\": \"Failed\",\r\n        \"message\": \"Failed to download 
>   package.\r\nAppGallery Deploy Failed: 'System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.\r\n   at 
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)\r\n   at 
>   System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at 
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task 
>   task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.AppGalleryPackage.&amp;amp;amp;lt;Download&amp;amp;amp;gt;d__a.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from 
>   previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at 
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at 
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.AppGalleryPackage.&amp;amp;amp;lt;Download&amp;amp;amp;gt;d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where 
>   exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at 
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at 
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.DeploymentController.&amp;amp;amp;lt;DownloadPackageAndSettings&amp;amp;amp;gt;d__27.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from 
>   previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at 
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at 
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.DeploymentController.&amp;amp;amp;lt;DownloadAndDeployPackage&amp;amp;amp;gt;d__17.MoveNext()'\r\nFailed to download 
>   package.\r\nAppGallery Deploy Failed: 'System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.\r\n   at 
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)\r\n   at 
>   System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at 
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task 
>   task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.AppGalleryPackage.&amp;amp;lt;Download&amp;amp;gt;d__a.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous 
>   location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at 
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at 
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.AppGalleryPackage.&amp;amp;lt;Download&amp;amp;gt;d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where 
>   exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at 
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at 
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.DeploymentController.&amp;amp;lt;DownloadPackageAndSettings&amp;amp;gt;d__27.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous 
>   location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at 
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at 
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.DeploymentController.&amp;amp;lt;DownloadAndDeployPackage&amp;amp;gt;d__17.MoveNext()'\r\nFailed to download 
>   package.\r\nAppGallery Deploy Failed: 'System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.\r\n   at 
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)\r\n   at 
>   System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at 
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task 
>   task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.AppGalleryPackage.&amp;lt;Download&amp;gt;d__a.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location 
>   where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at 
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at 
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.AppGalleryPackage.&amp;lt;Download&amp;gt;d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was 
>   thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at 
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at 
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.DeploymentController.&amp;lt;DownloadPackageAndSettings&amp;gt;d__27.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location 
>   where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at 
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at 
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.DeploymentController.&amp;lt;DownloadAndDeployPackage&amp;gt;d__17.MoveNext()'\r\nFailed to download package.\r\nAppGallery 
>   Deploy Failed: 'System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.\r\n   at 
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)\r\n   at 
>   System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at 
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task 
>   task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.AppGalleryPackage.&lt;Download&gt;d__a.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where 
>   exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at 
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at 
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.AppGalleryPackage.&lt;Download&gt;d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown 
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at 
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at 
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.DeploymentController.&lt;DownloadPackageAndSettings&gt;d__27.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where 
>   exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at 
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at 
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.DeploymentController.&lt;DownloadAndDeployPackage&gt;d__17.MoveNext()'\r\nFailed to download package.\r\nAppGallery Deploy 
>   Failed: 'System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.\r\n   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult 
>   asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)\r\n   at 
>   System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at 
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task 
>   task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.AppGalleryPackage.<Download>d__a.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was 
>   thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at 
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at 
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.AppGalleryPackage.<Download>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
>    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task 
>   task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.DeploymentController.<DownloadPackageAndSettings>d__27.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous 
>   location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at 
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at 
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.DeploymentController.<DownloadAndDeployPackage>d__17.MoveNext()'\"\r\n      }\r\n    ]\r\n  }\r\n}"
>             }
>           ]
>         }
>       ]
>     }
>   }'

Comment: Are you pulling anything from github.com there by any chance?

Comment: Just the ARM template itself (JSON) is hosted on github:https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Azure-Quickstart-Templates/master/Sitecore%208.2.3/xp0/azuredeploy.json

Comment: Okay, try this workaround in PowerShell (before invoking `New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment`): https://github.com/snobu/tls-negotiations#powershell-invoke-webrequest-and-invoke-restmethod - it's probably related to this change: https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/

Comment: You should also try this `iwr https://ACCOUNT.blob.core.windows.net/`, the result should be a query parameter error but not a TLS one.

Comment: @evilSnobu I get the query parameter error : iwr : InvalidQueryParameterValueValue for one of the query parameters specified in the request URI is invalid.

Comment: when I try to download the package directy in Powershell using Invoke-WebRequest it works fine..

Comment: Any luck with setting the ServicePointManager before invoking your deployment? (my first link - https://github.com/snobu/tls-negotiations#powershell-invoke-webrequest-and-invoke-restmethod)

Comment: This ServicePointManager didn't fix it unfortunately. I guess that is because the connection fails between azure and azure-storage. My local machine has no problem with the resource

Comment: Where exactly are you running that PowerShell script? Under which Azure service?

Comment: I guess it is run on the other side of a Rest API handling the deployments on azure. That explains why changing local settings doesn't work. I have used both a local powershell ISE and cloud shell on azure

Answer (score 0):

For anyone's information (and future reference). I have figured out (part of) the problem. Looking with KUDU tools on the app service I was able to pinpoint more precisely the package that is the culprit. I have found the following error :

> Downloading package path 'Sitecore/Sitecore-Azure-Quickstart-Templates/releases/download/v1.5.0/SetCompatibilityLevel.scwdp.zip' from blob 'https://github.com'
>       
>       
>           Failed to download package.

So downloading a package from Github.com is the problem. I will try to alter the templates to get this elsewhere.